# Have yet to or Has yet to?

Tags: neither-nor

> A and B have yet to answer the question.

Or

> A or B has yet to answer the question.

Or

> Neither of A or B has yet to answer the question.

Which is the best?

Thank you very much for your answer and edit.

Comment: Thank you, Eddie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all have different meanings

The first is fine.  It is rather formal and in this context could easily be replaced with a simple negative.

The second *should* be replaced by a negative, the construction is confusing and hard to understand. "A and B haven't both answered the question".  It would be better, if you know, to write "A has answered, but B hasn't." This adds extra useful information.

The third has a kind of double negative and should (some grammarians would say "must") be re-written: "A and B have [both] answered the question."

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.